# Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory problem again after fixing it

Tags: spring-boot

I got this problem, i got error Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory, I fixed it when i delete my working table in postgresql and then initiliaze it again, but it is working only for some time, when I try to add something, or change anything to improve the code i get this error again.
This is my Entity:

```
  package com.jrp.pma.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_accounts")
public class UserAccount {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="user_accounts_seq")
@Column(name = "user_id")
private long userId;

@Column(name = "username")
private String userName;

private String email;

private String password;

private boolean enabled= true;
```

And this is the error itself

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    [2m2021-04-20 12:09:44.882[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m11580[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.jrp.pma.entities.UserAccount]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
        at com.jrp.pma.ProjectManagementApplication.main(ProjectManagementApplication.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.jrp.pma.entities.UserAccount]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.jrp.pma.entities.UserAccount]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.lambda$new$1(SessionFactoryImpl.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1766) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: The increment size of the [user_accounts_seq] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].
        at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.configure(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.29.Final.jar:5.4.29.Final]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Last time i fixed it with just drop the tables in  POSTGRESQL, but as i said, after i try to add someting to code, and restart it, this error is displayed, I think its something wrong with database, do you have any idea?
BTW it`s from udemy course for Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the  `@SequenceGenerator` annotation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="user_accounts_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_accounts_seq", sequenceName = "user_accounts_seq", allocationSize = 5)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private long userId;
```

Also, make sure that the `user_accounts_seq` sequence exists in Postgres and that the user you are using to connect to the database has access to said sequence (in Postgres [access grants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-grant.html) for tables and sequences are seperate!).

You can create a sequence as follows:

```
CREATE
SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS public.user_accounts_seq START
WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 5 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE CACHE 1;
```

You can grant access to sequences in the `public` schema as follows:

```
 grant all privileges on all sequences in schema public to YOUR_USER;
```

And btw, dropping all tables is not really a fix for a problem :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. And for the tables, I have no idea actually, I saw it from somewhere and just try it :D, learning SQL and SPRING from a week, and yea..

Comment: @GeorgeMarizov glad to hear! Can you then please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted answer?

Comment: I cannot upvote it because i have new account, but i mark it as accepted :)